# Can you share `cfg!` up the dependency tree using Cargo?

Tags: configuration, rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust library that has some platform abstractions in the form of "backends". The library uses a `build.rs` to do some platform checks and sets some compile time configuration variables according to what backends can be built. Then in the code, backend code is guarded like this:

```
#[cfg(backend1)]
struct Backend1 { ... }
#[cfg(backend2)]
struct Backend2 { ... }
...
```

A consumer of this library wants to instantiate a backend suitable for the current platform. Ideally you'd do something like:

```
fn get_backend() -> Box<Backend> {
    #[cfg(backend1)]
    return mylib::backends::Backend1::new(...);
    #[cfg(backend2)]
    return mylib::backends::Backend2::new(...);
    ...
}
```

However, the configuration variables inside `mylib` do not get shared to consumers, so `#[cfg(backend1)]` won't work as expected.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour without requiring manual intervention for the person building the consumer of the library? I don't want users to have to manually pass a list of available backends. It seems this should be automatable.

Note that the structs for backends not built-in to `mylib` are totally absent, meaning that consumers can't reference them. Consumers would need to use conditional compilation to ensure that only backends built in to `mylib` are referenced.

There may be more than one backend for any given platform, and in that case, the consumer should be able to choose which one.

Comment: In all the libs built like this I saw, there is a default backend, and the user can select another backend with an option.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to a library's config from outside.

You will never be able to know the concrete types of the backends from consumer code, so you have to come up with some machinery to be able to construct them, taking into account the different needs of each of their constructors.

The basic idea here, is to introduce a context, something like a dependency injection context that you might use in an object-oriented language. The context holds values that might be needed by a constructor.

To create trait objects, you need a trait:

```
pub trait Backend {
    // all the common stuff for backends
}
```

A trait for constructing backends, and a struct to hold all the possible configuration variables needed by these backends. This can't be the same trait as `Backend` because the `new` method prevents it from being made into an object. Most of the variables are optional, since not all backends need them:

```
pub trait BackendContstruct {
    fn new(ctx: &BackendContext) -> Result<Box<Backend>, BackendError>;
}

pub struct BackendContext<'a> {
    var_1: Option<&'a str>,
    var_2: Option<&'a str>,
    another: Option<bool>,
    // etc
}
```

If you provide the wrong variables, then you need to get an error back. Making the construction dynamic unfortunately means that errors are runtime instead of at compile-time:

```
pub struct BackendError(String);
```

The availability of each backend depends on platform support. So make their definitions dependant on the platform:

```
#[cfg(platform1)]
mod backend1 {
    pub struct Backend1;
    impl ::Backend for Backend1 {}
    impl ::BackendContstruct for Backend1 {
        fn new(ctx: &::BackendContext) -> Result<Box<::Backend>, ::BackendError> {
            if ctx.var_1.is_none() {
                Err(::BackendError("Backend1 requires val_1 to initialize".to_string()))
            } else {
                Ok(Box::new(Backend1 {}))
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(platform1)]
#[cfg(platform2)]
mod backend2 {
    pub struct Backend2;
    impl ::Backend for Backend2 {}
    impl ::BackendContstruct for Backend2 {
        fn new(ctx: &::BackendContext) -> Result<Box<::Backend>, ::BackendError> {
            Ok(Box::new(Backend2 {}))
        }
    }
}
```

None of the concrete types are public, and any might just not exist. So provide an enum so that consumers can specify which backend they want:

```
pub enum BackendType {
    // these names are available in all configurations
    Default, Backend1, Backend2, Backend3
}
```

And a function for constructing the backends. It will be an `Err` to request an unsupported backend or to miss out required variables in the context. Consumers should be encouraged to use the `Default` variant, which should have a valid backend on any platform:

```
pub fn create_backend(backend: BackendType, ctx: &BackendContext) -> Result<Box<Backend>, BackendError> {
    match backend {
        #[cfg(platform1)]
        #[cfg(platform2)]
        BackendType::Default => Backend2::new(ctx),
        #[cfg(platform1)]
        BackendType::Backend1 => Backend1::new(ctx),
        #[cfg(platform1)]
        #[cfg(platform2)]
        BackendType::Backend2 => Backend2::new(ctx),
        _ => Err(BackendError("Backend not available".to_string()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the client would be able to choose one of the available backends at its compile time. This would work if there is exactly one backend per platform, but this may not be the case.

Comment: (as it happens the API is generic using a trait, but the `new` is backend specific because of differing configuration options)

Comment: Then you probably should be have a config per platform instead of per backend.

Comment: I think you need to update your question to include these points, since an answer that takes those into account will not be an answer to your more broad question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that returns a list of backends available.

Then, when an app wants to use your library, it can call that function from its `build.rs`, select one of the backends available, and pass it as an option to the compiler.

Comment: The problem is still that the code in the question is trying to use the types statically. The function to return the list of backends would be dynamic, and you would have to construct the backends dynamically too.

Comment: if you guard use of the backend-specific parts inside a  `#[cfg(has_backend1)] {...}`, if the library didn't have backend1 it's as if the guarded code didn't exist.

Comment: I misread the answer. It could actually work. Though it does commit consumers of the library to using a build script.